# Reproducir vídeo en una página web desde un móvil

Tags: wordpress, web, video, youtube

Estoy desarrollando una web y tengo que utilizar un vídeo como fondo en la cabecera. Desde el ordenador se reproduce sin problemas, pero desde el móvil no va. Quería saber si para que pueda reproducirse en el vídeo desde el móvil, qué formato debería tener o qué otras características debería tener en cuenta. Actualmente el vídeo está en formato .mp4 y su peso es de 60MB (me lo enviaron así). También pensé en subirlo desde YouTube para reducir el peso y que no pierda calidad, pero he pensado en que se vería el logo de YouTube y el reproductor, si hay alguna forma de que haya alguna forma de quitarlo. En estos casos, ¿qué me recomendáis?

Gracias,
Un saludo.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que no se te ve? ¿Se te queda el espacio que ocupa el vídeo en blanco? ¿El vídeo está en autoplay? ¿Tiene el sonido activado inicialmente?

Comment: Aparte del problema que tienes, es recomendable que ajustes el video para su uso en dispositivos móviles. 60 megabytes pudieran ser demasiados para datos móviles, no me refiero a velocidad, sino al consumo de datos al que estás exponiendo a un potencial visitante de tu página. Saludos

Comment: Que pasa si ensayas con la consola de des arrolladores y simulas el móvil? desaparece igual o se ve, así sería más  fácil ver si tú problema es el tamaño, el dispositivo o el video, de igual forma deberías disminuir el peso

Comment: Tiene activado la opción autoplay, pero en el móvil el vídeo aparece como congelado.

Comment: Si ensayo con la con la consola y simulo el móvil, el vídeo arranca, pero si entras desde el móvil, el vídeo se congela.

Comment: ¿Hasta que tamaño máximo es recomendable?